# How to apply Business Logic with Data Binding in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Does anyone have an example of applying complex business logic in an application where databinding is used?

I have never used data binding because it never fits perfectly into any application.  Even with a simple data-centric WinForms application, there are business rules that apply to WHAT may happen with a record, WHEN it must happen, or WHO may cause it to happen...

...maybe a certain user cannot update a record but they may view it.

...maybe a record cannot be updated because of its current status.

...maybe a record has an "IsDeleted" or "DateDeleted" flag.

I have always created classes with very specific operations in a business class and checked security, conditions of the record, and the like.  This makes it very difficult to actually BIND to a collection of objects in the way Microsoft preaches.

I would be grateful for any helpful samples or links.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Not at all sure I understand the question, but if so, then the key to this is that your business objects must be transacted or 'rollbackable', and must implement the binding-related interfaces. Then your validation of business rules takes place in teh object(s) and if it fails, the object can be rolled back to its prior state.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a [Presentation (or View) Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

This allows you to pull in all the operations you need to bind complex user interactions in the UI to without coupling yourself to individual UI elements.

It's used pretty extensively in XAML applications using the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Elsewhere you can see this in action on the web in [JavaScript with AngualJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

**As for WinForms... It really is a poor platform to use extensive data binding in because it simply doesn't support it well**. You are better off using a [Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx) pattern in WinForms, but you will inevitably have to wire things up in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the MVVM pattern that is implemented in the WPF architecture. Here is a very helpful link.

Joel Cochran, who works for Microsoft posted this and it is extremely helpful for just starting in WPF and MVVM
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BClf7GZR0DQ

By the time you finish this you should have a clear understanding of Data Binding and the MVVM pattern. Hope this helps.

Also, in agreement with Josh's post about WinForms not being a good platform for implementing this.